# Django peculiar behavior for model queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a model with the following structure

```
class Lease(models.Model):
    ....
    rent_category = models.ForeignKey( Category )
    building = models.ForeignKey( Building )
```

I have a form against this model, and is working fine.

But when i go to the shell and and try to query the model, it doesn't see the building field!

```
>>> from pms.models import Lease
>>> lease = Lease.objects.all()
>>> lease[0].building
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 315, in __get__
    rel_obj = QuerySet(self.field.rel.to).using(db).get(**params)
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 349, in get
    % self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Building matching query does not exist.
```

The building field exist in the database.
Very strange behavior!!

Paul

Comment: Try `Building.objects.get(pk=lease[0].building_id)`. What do you get?

Comment: When i do dir(Lease), am able to see the 'building' field!!

Comment: Sure that exists in database? Please, post `print unicode(lease[0].pk)` and `select * from building where pk = *previus showed value`. Also show create table in mysql and sql from python manage.py ... I know, paranoid skeptics.

Comment: Than means you don't have `Building` row with pk which in `lease[0]`. May be you deleted it somehow. You can check it manually in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks DrTyrsa,

Your last point=True, 
i don't have a building with lease[0].building_id, i did lease[17].building and it returned me the correct result.

Thanks.